# Write KML file from another

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science, kml, pykml

I'm trying to:

```
- read a KML file
- remove the Placemark element if name = 'ZONE'
- write a new KML file without the element
```

This is my code:

```
from pykml import parser
kml_file_path = '../Source/Lombardia.kml'

removeList = list()

with open(kml_file_path) as f:
 folder = parser.parse(f).getroot().Document.Folder

for pm in folder.Placemark:
    if pm.name == 'ZONE':
        removeList.append(pm)
        print pm.name

for tag in removeList:
    parent = tag.getparent()
    parent.remove(tag)
#Write the new file
#I cannot reach the solution help me
```

and this is the KML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
<Document>
    <name>Lombardia</name>
    <Style>
    ...
    </Style>
    <Folder>
<Placemark>
            <name>ZOGNO</name>
            <styleUrl>#FEATURES_LABELS</styleUrl>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>9.680530595139061,45.7941656233647,0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>ZONE</name>
            <styleUrl>#FEATURES_LABELS</styleUrl>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>10.1315885854064,45.7592449779275,0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
    </Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

The problem is that when I write the new KML file this still has the element I want to delete.
In fact, with I want to delete the element that contains name = ZONE.
What i'm doing wrong?
Thank you.

**--- Final Code**
This is the working code thanks to @Dawid Ferenczy:

```
from lxml import etree
import pykml
from pykml import parser

kml_file_path = '../Source/Lombardia.kml'

# parse the input file into an object tree
with open(kml_file_path) as f:
  tree = parser.parse(f)

# get a reference to the "Document.Folder" node
folder = tree.getroot().Document.Folder

# iterate through all "Document.Folder.Placemark" nodes and find and remove all nodes
# which contain child node "name" with content "ZONE"
for pm in folder.Placemark:
    if pm.name == 'ZOGNO':
        parent = pm.getparent()
        parent.remove(pm)

# convert the object tree into a string and write it into an output file
with open('output.kml', 'w') as output:
    output.write(etree.tostring(folder, pretty_print=True))
```

Comment: That code doesn't make a sense at all. First, you parse the KML file using the XML library into a `tree` variable. Then you parse it again using the `pykml` library and you do some operations with the result. Finally, you just write the original untouched `tree` back into a file. I really have no clue what are your intentions here.

Comment: And you import `etree` from the library `lxml` which is never used. Why are you parsing it twice using two different libraries?

Comment: @DawidFerenczy Sorry i'm kinda tired today. I've posted the code without the test rows. But now i cannot figure out how to write again the file without the deleted element.

Comment: Does it work for you? I have tested it and it's working as expected.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy Hi, i've tested right now but it does not delete the element "ZONE" i'm trying to figure it out. Thanks a lot

Comment: Added the working code i was printing the wrong variable =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following issues in your code:

- you're not storing the whole parsed object tree anywhere (you have just a reference to the node "*Document.Folder*": `folder = parser.parse(f).getroot().Document.Folder`) but you want to write it back into a file so you need to store it
- I don't understand why you need two loops and the list `removeList` when you can delete elements directly in the first loop
- you're not reading the documentation - it's well described how to write the object tree into a file under [examples](https://pythonhosted.org/pykml/examples/kml_reference_examples.html) in pykml library's documentation

Try the following code:

```
from lxml import etree
from pykml import parser

kml_file_path = './input.kml'

# parse the input file into an object tree
with open(kml_file_path) as f:
  tree = parser.parse(f)

# get a reference to the "Document.Folder" node
folder = tree.getroot().Document.Folder

# iterate through all "Document.Folder.Placemark" nodes and find and remove all nodes 
# which contain child node "name" with content "ZONE"
for pm in folder.Placemark:
    if pm.name == 'ZONE':
        parent = pm.getparent()
        parent.remove(pm)

# convert the object tree into a string and write it into an output file
with open('output.kml', 'w') as output:
    output.write(etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True))
```

It's very simple:

- KML file is parsed into an object tree and stored in variable `tree`
- the same object tree is directly manipulated (removed element)
- the same object tree is written back into a file

Comment: The output.write call gives "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes".

Answer (score 2):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special purpose language designed to transform XML files. And because KML files *are* XML files, this solution is viable. Python's third-party module, `lxml` can run XSLT 1.0 scripts and do so without a single loop.

Specifically, the XSLT script runs the [Identity Transform](http://www.usingxml.com/Transforms/XslIdentity) to copy entire document as is. Then, script runs an empty template on the element (conditional to specific logic) to remove that element. To accommodate the default namespace, a prefix, *doc*, is used for XPath search.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file to be loaded in Python below)*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:doc="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="doc:Placemark[doc:name='ZONE']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[XSLT Fiddle Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzQC)

**Python**

```
import lxml.etree as et

# LOAD XML AND XSL
doc = et.parse('/path/to/Input.xml')
xsl = et.parse('/path/to/XSLT_Script.xsl')

# CONFIGURE TRANSFORMER
transform = et.XSLT(xsl)    

# RUN TRANSFORMATION
result = transform(doc)

# PRINT RESULT
print(result)  

# SAVE TO FILE
with open('output.xml', 'wb') as f:
   f.write(result)
```

**Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
   <Document>
      <name>Lombardia</name>
      <Style>
    ...
    </Style>
      <Folder>
         <Placemark>
            <name>ZOGNO</name>
            <styleUrl>#FEATURES_LABELS</styleUrl>
            <Point>
               <coordinates>9.680530595139061,45.7941656233647,0</coordinates>
            </Point>
         </Placemark>
      </Folder>
   </Document>
</kml>
```